# Prove two value are equal

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Here $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that
$
\min(S) = -\max(-S).
$

My thought:
Suppose $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. 
We will show that if $\min(S)=M,$ then $-\max(-S)=M.$ and if $-\max(-S)=M,$ then $\min(S)=M.$

Suppose $\min(S)=M.$ Let $-x\in -S$ be given. It follows that $x\in S.$ Thus, $x\geq M.$ So $-x\leq -M.$ Remark that $-M\in -S$ as $M\in S.$ Hence, $-M=\max(-S)$ or $\min(S)=-\max(-S).$

Suppose $\max(-S)=-M.$ Let $x\in S$ be given. It follows that $-x\in -S.$ Thus, $x\leq -M.$ So $-x\geq M.$ Remark that $M\in S$ as $-M\in -S.$ Hence, $M=\min(-S)$ or $\min(-S)=-\max(-S)$ as desired.

I feel like the above proof is not quite true. How do you actually prove two things are equal, what do you have to assume? Should you prove two direction?

Comment: The notation $\min(S)$ is usually understood to mean that the minimum is actually attained at some $x\in S$.  This would be so if $S$ were closed and bounded (at least from below), but in any case it would be helpful to have such assumptions about $S$ stated.

Comment: Or you could prove this: "$\min(S)=-\max(-S)$ if $\min(S)$ exists."

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $$m=\min\{x | x\in S\}=\min(S)$$ then for all $x \in S$ you have that $$x\ge m \implies -x\le-m$$ or equivalently $$-m=\max\{-x|x\in S\}=\max\{x|-x\in -S\}=\max(-S)$$ Now, since $m=-(-m)$ you have that $$m=\min(S)=-(-m)=-\max(-S)$$